# Make a view of a difference table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Lets imagine two tables - T_Name, T_nameAttributes

T_name

| Name | NameID |
| --- | --- |
| Sara | 2 |
| Matthew | 3 |

T_nameAttributes

| NameID | AttributeID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | Red Apple |
| 2 | 5 | $20 |

Originally retrieving data from them looks like this

```
select * 
from T_name 
left join T_nameAttributes 
    on T_name.NameID = T_nameAttributes.NameID 
    and AttributeID = 3 and nameID = 2
```

`Sara, 3, Red Apple`

Everyday those values saved into the same table schemas with an additional 'Date' column and all fine here, I can easily retrieve value on a requested date

**The problem here** - I want to save DB space and to store only changed values, so my log tables now look like that: (this part is already done)

T_NameLog

| Date | Name | NameID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | Sara | 2 |
| 2023-10-05 | Sarah | 2 // name changed |

T_nameAttributesLog

| Date | AttributeID | NameID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 3 | 2 | Red Apple |
| 2023-10-04 | 3 | 2 | Green Apple // value changed |
| 2023-01-01 | 5 | 2 | $20 |
| 2023-02-12 | 5 | 2 | $0 |
| 2023-10-09 | 5 | 2 | $70 |

**The question:** Both tables can change its values at the random days, I want to retrieve a joined tables with a rows based on an each day in a month

```
Select date, name, value 
from T_NameLog 
left join T_nameAttributesLog <...> 
where date between '2023-10-02' and '2023-10-05' 
and AttributeID = 3 and nameID = 2
```

expected results:

| date | name | attribute |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-02 | Sara | Red Apple |
| 2023-10-03 | Sara | Red Apple |
| 2023-10-04 | Sara | Green Apple |
| 2023-10-05 | Sarah | Green Apple |

Comment: I'm not really sure what's the question here - Is it how to log only the changes, or how to select also dates that doesn't appear in the log table?

Comment: On a side note: The first query will of course also select Matthew, because this is what an outer join is all about.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, my mistake, but it's irrelevant to main question, Matthew here just to represent data organization

Comment: @ZoharPeled the second one, sorry about unclear explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First generate a row per date. Then use `CROSS APPLY` with a `TOP` clause to get the most up-to-date rows of the tables. Instead of looking up only one name and one attribute, I have written my query so it can find all names and attributes. This is done with `TOP (1) WITH TIES` in combination with an `ORDER BY RANK()`.

If you want one name only or one attribute only, just comment out the ID conditions in the `WHERE` clauses. (But in that case it would suffice to have `TOP (1)` without the `WITH TIES` clause and a mere `ORDER BY [Date] DESC`.)

```
with 
  days as 
  (
    select cast('2023-10-02' as date) as dt,
           cast('2023-10-05' as date) as last_dt
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, dt),
           last_dt
    from days
    where dt < last_dt
  )
select days.dt, n.name, na.value
from days
cross apply
(
  select top (1) with ties
    nl.name,
    nl.nameid
  from t_namelog nl
  where nl.[Date] <= days.dt
  -- and nl.nameid = 2
  order by rank() over (partition by nl.nameid order by nl.[Date] desc)
) n
cross apply
(
  select top (1) with ties
    nal.value,
    nal.attributeid
  from t_nameattributeslog nal
  where nal.nameid = n.nameid
  and nal.[Date] <= days.dt
  -- and nal.attributeid = 3
  order by rank() over (partition by nal.attributeid order by nal.[Date] desc)
) na
order by days.dt, n.nameid, na.attributeid;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/WyhGYzqy

Comment: That's great thanks! I'll try that